# Spring BCryptPasswordEncoder некорректно работает

Tags: java, spring-security

Я использую BCryptPasswordEncoder для шифрования пароля при регистрации на сайте. Но есть проблема, при логине пароль пользователя не подтверждается. В классе BCryptPasswordEncoder есть метод, который сравнивает введенный пароль и зашифрованный из БД. Но в примерах это все работает на автомате на уровне Spring.

Security xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
         xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <http realm="BookManager"  auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"  >
        <intercept-url pattern="/add" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/remove" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/edit" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/books" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/login.jsp*" access="permitAll"/>

        <form-login login-page= "/login"
                             username-parameter= "username"
                             password-parameter= "password"
                             login-processing-url= "/login"
                             authentication-failure-url= "/login.jsp?error=true" />

        <logout logout-url= "/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url= "/index"/>
        <!--<form-login login-page="/login.jsp" default-target-url="/index.jsp"
                       authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?error=1" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/index" />-->

        <anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ROLE_ANONYMOUS" />
        <csrf disabled="true"/>



    <!--Save logged user in cookie with name key='name' -->
    <remember-me key= "myKey" token-validity-seconds= "300"/>

    </http>

    <!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
    <authentication-manager alias= "authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="customUserDetailsService">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>


    <!-- Use a SHA-1 encoder since the user's passwords are stored as SHA-1 in the database -->
    <b:bean id="encoder"
                class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <b:constructor-arg name="strength" value="11"/>
    </b:bean>

    <!-- A custom service where Spring will retrieve users and their corresponding access levels  -->
    <b:bean class="BookManager.Service.CustomUserDetailsService" id="customUserDetailsService">
        <b:property name="encoder" ref="encoder"/>
    </b:bean>

</b:beans>
```

Шифрование при добавлении пользователя

```
  public void addUser(User user)
      {
        user.setPassword(bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        userDao.addUser(user);
      }
```

Метод проверки пользователя

```
 public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String s) throws UsernameNotFoundException
      {
        UserDetails userDetails = null;
        User user = userService.searchUser(s);   

        userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                        user.getUsername(),
                        user.getPassword().toLowerCase(),
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        true,
                        getAuthorities(user.getAccess()));

        return userDetails;
      }
```

UPD В моем понимании все должно работать так: при вводе логина и пароля Spring вызывает метод loadUserByUsername, где по логину юзер достается из БД,Spring автоматически сравнивает введенный пароль с паролем из БД. Это работает. При подключении BCryptPasswordEncoder для сравнения паролей Spring должен вызывать метод аналогичен методу matches (или его же) автоматически. Но может я не правильно понимаю))
Делал по аналогии [статьи](https://hellokoding.com/registration-and-login-example-with-spring-xml-configuration-maven-jsp-and-mysql/)
Важно еще то, что когда подключен бин encoder то не логинится даже с не шифрованными паролями в бд, если отключаешь то все в порядке, кроме конечно шифрованных паролей.

Comment: не очень понятно в чем конкретно проблема. что значит некорректно работает? Нажмите Править под вопросом и добавьте ожидаемый результат

Comment: Мало информации. Вряд ли он может неправильно работать, скорее всего у вас где-то неверная проверка. При попытке залогиниться, вы должны загружать пользователя например по логину, и с помощью метода `matches` из `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, где первый аргумент - пароль, введенный пользователем, а второй аргумент - зашифрованный хранимый пароль, получать ответ и на его основе принимать решение, пускать пользователя или нет. У вас так?

Comment: Про метод matches я знаю, о в примерах он явно не вызывается. Думаю проблема в кроется в xml настройках.

Comment: возможно дело в toLowerCase() для пароля при сравнении

Comment: при создании вы используете `user.getPassword()`, при сравнении `user.getPassword().toLowerCase()`

Comment: @hardsky, Вы полностью правы, спасибо большое за ваш ответ, ошибка была как всегда в невнимательности))